# Force hover on HTML element

Tags: jquery, hover

I need to decieve an HTML element into thinking my cursor id hovering over it.

Can anyone tell me how I might accomplish this? I know I can to something like this `$(this).click()` to simulate a mouse click. I need an equivalent for hovering.

Thanks

Comment: $(this).trigger('mouseover') ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $(el).trigger('mouseover') but that will only execute any hover callbacks you've set up. It won't trigger the browser's hover detection such as for applying css hover rules.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/8VpzD/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#s').hover(function() { alert('Wee'); });

    $('#b').click(function() { $('#s').trigger('mouseover'); });
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to trigger CSS hover rules without adding classes?